# MonoTouch.Dialog LoadMoreElement blocking on delegate

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to use a LoadMoreElement object to display an activity indicator when the cell is clicked.  The below code works, however the NavigationController object is long running and the activity indicator only displays after the NavigationController has completed its work.  This kind of defeats the point of having an Activity Indicator as the app appears to hang for a while and then just flashes on the screen.

I think the NavigationController object is blocking and that's why the AcitivityIndicator isn't displaying.  Should I use a thread to allow this to complete in the background?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        var loadMore = new LoadMoreElement();
        loadMore.Caption = "Ratios";
        loadMore.NormalCaption = "Ratios";
        loadMore.LoadingCaption = "Loading Ratios...";
        loadMore.Tapped += delegate { loadMore.Animating = true; NavigationController.PushViewController(new FileListController(), true); };
        loadMore.Font = UIFont.FromName("Arial", 10);
        loadMore.TextColor = UIColor.Black;

        Root.Add(new Section() {                
            loadMore
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try invoking the ActivityIndicator on the main thread using [InvokeOnMainThread](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InvokeOnMainThread%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction%29), then pushing your new View controller.